# Selenium getting value of rapidly changing element StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: java, selenium

I need to get value of rapidly changing element (in this case a timer counting down in miliseconds) but when I try to use

```
String timeLeftString = driver.findElement(By.xpath(timerXpath)).getText();
```

it just throws StaleElementReferenceException and never actually gets the value of the element.

How would one test value of such element ?

Comment: Its's hard to say the cause of the issue without a link to the page or at least the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to your issue:

I would suggest you to induce FluentWait for the particular element. Now a few words about FluentWait, it is applied to elements which are visible at particular intervals after an action had taken place. For example a dropdown menu can have totally 3 items, with only one item displayed at a time for an interval of 3 seconds. So here, after performing the required action you have to induce FluentWait which will poll for the property of the particular element (visibility_of_the_element or element_to_be_clickable) in defined intervals (250 milliseconds) for a defined interval (total of 3 minutes). Additionally you have the flexibility to specify to handle the exception even which may occur within the defined total interval so that your testcase doesn't fails.

Let me know if this solution works for you.

Comment: @IgorVereš If this Answer have catered to your question can you please Accept it as a Solution to close the discussion thread. Thanks.